# How do I split this into partial sums?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given the series, $\sum(s_n - s_{n+1})$, 
can someone please explain to me how to split this into partial sums and the basic concept behind it?
I know that I can split it into $\sum s_n - \sum s_{n+1}$ but I don't know how to split it into partial sums.

Comment: I have added to my answer some stuff addressing the question in your comment. (Which you have deleted in the meantime.) Also the other answerer addressed this [in a comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264227/how-do-i-split-this-into-partial-sums#comment2567151_1264236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Just notice that the $n$-th partial sum is
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (s_k-s_{k+1}) = (s_1-s_2)+ (s_2-s_3) + \dots + (s_{n-1}-s_n)+(s_n-s_{n+1})= s_1-s_{n+1},$$
since all remaining terms cancel out.

(If you want a more formal proof, you can show this by induction.)

---

**EDIT:** The OP asked in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264227/how-do-i-split-this-into-partial-sums#comment2567124_1264236) and also in [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264266/how-do-we-use-partial-sums-to-prove-convergence) (which are now both deleted) how absolute convergence of $\sum (s_k-s_{k+1})$ relates to convergence of $(s_n)$ and $\sum s_n$.

---

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (s_k-s_{k+1})$ is absolutely convergent then it is also convergent.

Since the partial sums are equal to $s_1-s_{n+1}$ (see [another question posted by the same user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264227/how-do-i-split-this-into-partial-sums)), this implies that the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (s_1-s_{n+1})$ exists. Consequently, the sequence $s_n$ is convergent.

---

it seems possible that the OP might be interested not in convergence of the sequence $(s_n)$ but of the series $\sum s_n$.

Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |s_k-s_{k+1}|$ does not implies convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty s_k$.

To see this it suffices to notice that if we add arbitrary constant $c$ to the terms of sequence $(s_n)$, we get the same sum, since
$$|(s_k+c)-(s_{k+1}+c)|=|s_k-s_{k+1}|.$$
Therefore it is possible to choose $c$ in such way that $(s_k+c)$ is not convergent and therefore the series $\sum(s_k+c)$ does not converge either.

Answer (score 2):

You may write, for the partial sum:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^N(s_n-s_{n+1})&=\sum_{n=0}^Ns_n-\sum_{n=0}^Ns_{n+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^Ns_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}s_{n}\\\\
&=s_0+\sum_{n=1}^Ns_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}s_{n}-s_{N+1}\\\\
&=s_0-s_{N+1}
\end{align}
$$ that what is called 'telescoping'.

Comment: @user3097976 Please, I don't understand your question, I'm not sure about the series you are talking about, which one? Thanks.

Comment: @user3097976 The answer is no. Take for example $s_n=\frac1n$, you have that $\sum (s_n-s_{n+1})=\sum \frac1{n(n+1)}$ is absolutely convergent, but $\sum s_n=\sum \frac1n$ is **not** convergent.